# Repeat a number series based on a number

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a formula for this

1=1,2=2,3=3,4=1,5=2,6=3,7=1,8=2,9=3

I am trying to use this numbering system in an Excel spreadsheet by using a formula instead of a lookup function. I have a formula =COUNTIF(RANGE,CRITERIA) that can count each item in a column. The fomula I am looking for is    (COUNTIF=6) |SOME FORMULA| = 3

At present I am using a lookup function. I have 2 columns one lists 1:60000   and another column that repeats 1:6. I lookup the COUNTIF and the formula LOOKSUP the SERIES NUMBER.

Comment: do you mean the sequence $a_{3n-2} = 1$, $a_{3n-1} = 2$ and $a_{3n}=3$ for $n\geq 1$? Try using $\mod 3$.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for something along the lines of B1 ->  MOD(A1-1, 3)+1, based on the sample.  A1 contains the natural numbers, and B1 contains these reduced mod 3.

If you just want 1,2,3,1,2,3 etc, without row numbers, try A2 = MOD(A1, 3)+1.